# Deploying Grails on a Production Env. (Hibernate tries updating schema)

Tags: hibernate, grails, jboss, groovy

I am deploying to a unix box running Jboss. We are using SQL Server 2008 as our database. Once deployed  I push the changes by re-deploying the war to the environment.

I see server.log has errors, seems hibernate tries to re-generate/modify tables already created. I am using `dbCreate = "update"` setting in my `datasource.groovy` file.

Could anyone let me know the best practice for db settings so that I dont see these errors in the log file.

Thanks,
Appreciated.
WB

`2010-09-09 15:32:35,012 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (main) Unsuccessful: alter table.....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are managing the schema yourself, just comment out `dbCreate` entirely or use `dbCreate = "validate"`.

You might want to check out the [Liquibase plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/liquibase) to do automated database migration similar to ActiveRecord::Migration in Rails

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that error because there is a change in your domain objects that grails/hibernate cannot successful execute, probably do to constraints of data.

changing the dbCreate value might remove the error in the log, but I suspect the application will fail elsewhere